# TableView Crashing while reording when taking section

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

```
class TableViewController: UIViewController,UITableViewDelegate,UITableViewDataSource {

@IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!


var array = ["1","2","3"]

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.tableView.register(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "reuseIdentifier")
    tableView.delegate = self
    tableView.isScrollEnabled = false
    tableView.dragInteractionEnabled = true
    tableView.dragDelegate = self
    tableView.dropDelegate = self
}

// MARK: - Table view data source

func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of sections
    return array.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of rows
    return 1
}


func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "reuseIdentifier", for: indexPath)
    cell.textLabel?.text = array[indexPath.section]



    return cell
}
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, moveRowAt sourceIndexPath: IndexPath, to destinationIndexPath: IndexPath) {
    let item = array[sourceIndexPath.section]
    array[sourceIndexPath.section] = array[destinationIndexPath.section]
    array[destinationIndexPath.section] = item
    tableView.beginUpdates()
    tableView.reloadData()
    tableView.endUpdates()

}
```

}

```
extension TableViewController: UITableViewDragDelegate {
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, itemsForBeginning session: UIDragSession, at indexPath: IndexPath) -> [UIDragItem] {
        return [UIDragItem(itemProvider: NSItemProvider())]
    }
}

extension TableViewController: UITableViewDropDelegate {
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, performDropWith coordinator: UITableViewDropCoordinator) {
    }
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, dropSessionDidUpdate session: UIDropSession, withDestinationIndexPath destinationIndexPath: IndexPath?) -> UITableViewDropProposal {
        if tableView.hasActiveDrag {
            if session.items.count > 1 {
                return UITableViewDropProposal(operation: .cancel)
            } else {
                return UITableViewDropProposal(operation: .move, intent: .insertAtDestinationIndexPath)
            }
        } else {
            return UITableViewDropProposal(operation: .copy, intent: .insertAtDestinationIndexPath)
        }
    }
}
```

This code crashes with this error when I try to reorder the cells. It works perfectly fine when instead of section I do it in rows.

Here is the error log:

> TableViewSample[45038:397348] *** Terminating app due to uncaught
>   exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'attempt to move
>   index path ( {length = 2, path = 2 -
>   0}) to index path ( {length = 2, path
>   = 0 - 1}) that does not exist - there are only 1 rows in section 0 after the update'

Comment: What do you reorder ? Could you detail ?

Comment: 'Reording'?  Or reordering?

Comment: You are using the sourceIndexPath and destinationIndexPath parameters incorrectly, obviously.

Answer (score 1):

You switched the return values of these two methods:

```swift
func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of sections
    return 1
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of rows
    return array.count

}
```

Comment: Yes @koen I know that works, But due to some other condition we want to go as sections and then 1 row in each section.